# Taming big bad Blender

Tags: command-line, source-code, compile

**How big is Blender lite and headless (uncompressed) on Linux?**

[Blender 3.5.1](https://www.blender.org/download/release/Blender3.5/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64.tar.xz/) uncompressed is roughly 1250 MB. I can delete directories like addons, Eevee engine, built-in world shaders/EXRs, and still use it without crashing, but it's still too large (800 MB).

I don't want to download all 10+ GB of [sources](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu#Download_Sources) and [libraries](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu#Download_Libraries), and debug/compile for hours only to find out lite version is still too large for my use case (target is between 250 MB and 500 MB).

I have already tried to [`make headless lite`](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Options#Build_Targets) and encountered problems. I am wondering if it will be worth the effort in debugging (worth it if lite version is less than 500 MB).

If there are pre-built lite and headless Linux builds, that would be even better.

---

**EDIT:** I got `make headless lite` to work, but it is still 790 MB uncompressed. This still includes unneeded files like `bin/<version>/datafiles/studiolights` which can be removed to reduce size.

- `lite`: `blender` executable is 80 MB, `lib/` 256 MB, `<version>/python` 425 MB.
- Official release: `blender` executable is 250 MB, `lib/` 315 MB, `<version>/python` 280 MB (much smaller for some reason).

`make lite headless bpy` is 590 MB total (`bin/` 290 MB, `lib/` 105 MB). This still includes `bpy/<version>/datafiles/fonts` and others which can be removed to save space. `lite` does not include Cycles and Eevee engines, so it's unlikely to fit into my hard limit of 500 MB.